# Django autocomplete from json

Tags: python, json, django, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I'm trying to add some autocomplete field in Django Admin (Django 2.0.1).
I managed to get it to work (both with the autocomplete included in Django and with Select2) because in those cases I loaded the dropdown options from a ForeignKey field.

Now I need to have autocomplete on a simple CharField but the choices need to be taken from a remote API that return a json response. I can decide how to structure the json response. Any way to do this?
The returned json responde doesn't represent objects of model, just simple text options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your needs, but here was a solution to a similar problem (remote API, JSON, autocomplete text input). Select portions of the code:

**HTML**

```
<label>Which student? (search by last name.)</label>
<input type="text" name="studentname" id="student_name">
```

**JS**

```
// Build list of all students - hit API.
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "example.com/api/student/?format=json", true);
ajax.onload = function() {
    students = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    list = students.map(function(i) { 
        name = i.last_name + ', ' + i.first_name;
        return name;
    });
    var input = document.getElementById("student_name");
    new Awesomplete(input, { list: list });
};
ajax.send();
```

All this of course requires [the Awesomplete JS library](https://github.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete).

This is a solution when working outside the Django admin, but I think could be adapted to work within the admin setting without too much difficulty?

Perhaps something like this in your `ModelAdmin`?

```
def special_field(self, obj):
    return render_to_string('special.html')
special_field.allow_tags = True
```

Then throw the aforementioned HTML/JS in `special.html`.

Finally you'll need to remove the old field from your `ModelAdmin`, add your new custom field, and likely override your `ModelForm` - something like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    extra_input = self.cleaned_data.get('studentname', None)
    self.instance.full_name = extra_input  # the model instance to save to
    return super(NameOfYourForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just a couple of changes. I did everything in admin.py, I didn't use forms.py. I had to modify the save function like this def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        extra_input = request.POST.getlist('studentname')
        form.instance.name = extra_input[0]  # the model instance to save to
        return super(HumanAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)